# Tracking Reference to Native Reference problem - C# to C++/CLI to C++ AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, pass-by-reference

I am trying to write a C++/CLI wrapper using VS2010 against an C++ API for which I only have access to header files, and a dll/lib file.

I'm running into a problem with the bubbling back up of a native reference from the native code, to the tracking reference in the C# code.  I get a SystemAccessViolation.  The code is as follows:

Unmanaged Native C++ Headers for native Functions that returns a reference to Create the as well as to Modify the CustomObject:

```
class ManageCustomObject;
    _declspec(dllimport) errorCode CreateCustomObject(CustomObject& customObject);
    _declspec(dllimport) errorCode ModifyCustomObject(CustomObject& customObject);
```

Important thing to note about CustomObject is that it has private constructors only:

```
CustomObject(const CustomObject&) { }
CustomObject& operator=(const CustomObject&) { return *this; }
```

Now, my C++/CLI layer Method looks like this:

```
public ref class WrapperManageCustomObject {
public:
        errorCode WrapperCreateCustomObject(CustomObject% customObject)
        {
            return CreateCustomObject(customObject);
       }

        errorCode WrapperModifyCustomObject(CustomObject% customObject)
        {
            return ModifyCustomObject(customObject);
        }
};
```

And the wrapper for the CustomObject looks like this:

```
public class WrapperCustomObject : public CustomObject {
    public:
        WrapperCustomObject(const CustomObject&) {};
};
```

In C# the code goes as follows:

```
WrapperCustomObject wrapperCustomObject;
WrapperManageCustomObject wrapperManageCustomObject = new WrapperManageCustomObject();

long result;

// this works great
result = wrapperManageCustomObject.CreateCustomObject(ref wrapperCustomObject);

// can utilize wrapperCustomObject here with other native functions no problem, so long as I don't try to modify it...
...

// this throws an AccessViolationException was unhandled message
// essentially I am modifying / returning a different native customObject (though I'm not 100% sure what it does as I do not have access to the code)
result = wrapperManageCustomObject.ModifyCustomObject(ref wrapperCustomObject);
```

As you can see in my comments, the attempt to modify that object via reference throw an "AccessViolationException was unhandled : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Now, if I eliminate C# and the tracking reference from this equation and do this all within C++ or C++/CLI (so long as the tracking reference is not present), this works fine.  I assume this has something to do with native code trying to access updating a reference that is now in managed-land.

Is there any way around any of this to essentially make this code "work" from within C#? There is no way to pass a native reference to C# that I am aware of.

Comment: How are you supposed to create a `CustomObject` in C++ land if it has a private constructor and there are no factory functions?  You need to already have a `CustomObject` instance in order to call the `CreateCustomObject` helper function.

Comment: How did you get this to compile?  You are returning a *native* object pointer but the C# code is treating it as a *managed* wrapper.  Yes, big kaboom when you use it.  The native object pointer should be a private member of the wrapper.

Comment: Stu - I can do these as an "out" param too, but that's about it.  Ref params are a c# thing.

Comment: Hans - C++/CLI allows for a tracking reference.  Believe it or not, this actually works.

Comment: Adam - you don't have to create CustomObject in C++ land if the function is already returning a reference to one - meaning, I assume that .cpp file that I cannot see IS where the instance is created and held. You just need a container to hold that reference. i.e.: CustomObject customObject; before you call that function.

Comment: @Brian : I agree with Hans here; I don't know why you think the existence of tracking references changes the validity of his statement. Also, when addressing people, please prefix their name with `@` so they get notified in their SO inbox.

Comment: @ildjarn, OK. Agreed. However even if I did something like private: CustomObject _customObject; within the Public class WrapperCustomObject (no class inheritance from native base type) I still get the same error. Whereas if I do this entirely in unmanaged C++ it works fine.  The tracking reference I use to point to the instance of the wrapper class is causing the barf.

Comment: @Brian : The idiomatic approach is to make that `private: CustomObject* _customObject;`, and implement a dispose implementation and finalizer to make sure it gets cleaned up.

Comment: @ildjarn: again, agreed. these are all things i would do if i had proper access to the underling C++ dll source, but i do not. in the meantime, these are all workarounds as best as i can get to work successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed references are absolutely nothing like native references. Managed references are more like native pointers. As far as I am aware, you can't do somthing like `public class WrapperCustomObject : public CustomObject` (where `CustomObject` is a native class) and ever expect that to work. When you create a managed class, you are telling the CLR that your class will be well behaved in the face of being moved around in memory. If `CustomObject` does anything with pointers at all, that's no longer going to be true. `CustomObject` does not use managed references, and therefore the runtime has no way of knowing where to update clients if/when that class instance gets moved around.

Even worse, your wrapper is allowing that class to be instantiated without going through the factory method. Therefore, if the factory method `CreateCustomObject` does anything important to the object you get back, you've violated the contract of the code you're calling, which asked you to create instances of that object through the factory method only.

Comment: Oddly enough, you can actually get public class WrapperCustomObject as a managed derived class to inherit from public CustomObject (a non-managed native class) and it actually will "work".  However, as you pointed out and I agree - the limitations can build up quickly and I agree with what you say.

Comment: Maybe perhaps what I'm looking for now is any possible way to get around this methodology to something that "may work correctly". I cannot seem to find any way to do something useful when the CreateCustomObject returns that object by reference only - and that is the only way I can effectively create or hold it.  Working with references is very difficult - you cannot store them at all except for potentially a C++ static singular instance, OR, as I have demonstrated - a tracking reference to it held via Managed C#.

Comment: @Brian: No, it doesn't actually "work" -- just because it compiles doesn't mean it doesn't fail at runtime (and in fact it does). It compiles because the C++ class *could* be stateless, or *could* be pointerless, in which case it would work. But given you don't know the implementation of the class, it's not something you can rely upon. As for working with references being "difficult", they're only difficult if you try to think of native references as managed references. They have nothing to do with one another. If you want a managed reference create one.

Comment: @Brian: You cannot turn a managed reference into a native reference or vice versa. Period. If you want a wrapper, you actually have to make a wrapper, and expose managed equivelents for the native methods.

Comment: agreed. All my research has pointed out there is no way to retrieve a native reference from a managed / tracking reference.  However, I still note that once outward, a tracking reference from with C++/CLI can "work" - EVEN back inward to unmanaged code, so long as the target reference object does not change in the unmanaged code - as the unmanaged code cannot access the managed stack. Agreed also, that further - it depends on a stateless instance of that class created.  Solution here is to hold any native references within native code only - don't get tracking references involved

Comment: can't change the underlying code. if the compiled code creates the instance there and passes by reference, well... i'm subject to that code's bidding. :)

Comment: @Codemouse: You can just copy the target of the reference. Or store a pointer to it. Or with with it as a native reference any other way native references can be operated upon. You just can't do that kind of work from inside C#.